# WPF Slider and dates

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, slider

I want to make slider to select dates. For example, every hour in last two days. Also slider should has a legend on the bottom with values. How could I do it?

I made slider with data context as DoubleCollection from total hours in date and changed tooltip using custom ValueConverter. But when I change value, tooltip shows real values - total hours in date. Also I have no idea how to add a legend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example. First we create a slider from 0 to 48 rounded to integer values (`TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"`) then add a `TextBlock` bound to the slider value.

A `ValueConverter` is used to convert the 0-48 value into a date.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:HourToDateConverter x:Key="MyHourConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider x:Name="MySlider" Minimum="0" Maximum="48" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MySlider, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource MyHourConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace StackOverflow2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public class HourToDateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            object result = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            if (value is double)
                result = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours((double)value);
            return result;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer explains what I've already know, nevertheless I marked it as an answer.

Comment: Is there something that is still missing to fully answer your question?