# WPF MVVM MahApps range slider with dates in tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mahapps.metro

Using the following https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/rangeslider in a WPF MVVM application.  Currently the tooltip shows the numerical value and I wish to show a date instead.

I found the converter below in the following answer [WPF Slider and dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766445/wpf-slider-and-dates)

```
    public class HourToDateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            object result = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            if (value is double)
                result = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours((double)value);
            return result;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I have been able to successfully get a `TextBlock` to show the date range, however, I would like to show the same in the tool tip.

Is this possible?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the `AutoToolTipTextConverter` property to an instance of your converter class:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:HourToDateConverter x:Key="HourToDateConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Controls:RangeSlider x:Name="xxx"
                Minimum="10"
                Maximum="100"
                AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" AutoToolTipPrecision="2" MoveWholeRange="True"
                IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" ExtendedMode="True"
                AutoToolTipTextConverter="{StaticResource HourToDateConverter}">
    </Controls:RangeSlider>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How would you pass multiple parameters to converter?

Comment: I found a way to avoid multiple parameters, I was looking into the github and it appears the `AutoToolTipTextConverter` only supports `IValueConverter` and not `IMultiValueConverter`.  Thank you for your help.